Async send goal get blocks even after action server calls succeed
I have the problem that I am calling an action server with gh = client->async_send_goal(goal, options).get(). In the logs I can see that the server finished the execution callback so I assume that the get function on the async goal should return but it does not.
In the below code the first log output is the log before the async send goal, then all the execute logs but the "command finished async goal" never gets printed. The last log output is "command goal handle succeed". It is also worth noting that none of the log outputs of the option callbacks appear in the terminal.
action client
auto options = rclcpp_action::Client<Command>::SendGoalOptions();
options.result_callback = std::bind(result_cb, this, std::placeholders::_1);
options.feedback_callback = std::bind(feedback_cb, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
options.goal_response_callback = std::bind(goal_response_cb, this, std::placeholders::_1);

RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "command sending async goal");
gh_ = ac_->async_send_goal(goal, options).get();
RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "command finished async goal");

action server
void execute(const std::shared_ptr<Command> goal_handle)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("command"), "execute command");
    auto result = std::make_shared<Command::Result>();
    auto goal = goal_handle->get_goal();
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("command"), "execute command: got goal");
    auto command = static_cast<CommandEnum>(goal->command);
    auto feedback = std::make_shared<Command::Feedback>();

    actor->SetMachineDistance(currentMachineDistanceEstimate);
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("command"), "execute command: set machine dist");
    if (!actor->RunCommandAndWait(command, goal->machine_id, goal->machine_point, 60s))
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("command"), "execute command: success false");
        result->successful = false;
        goal_handle->abort(result);
    }
    else
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("command"), "execute command: success true");
        result->successful = true;
        goal_handle->succeed(result);
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("command"), "command goal handle succeed");
    }
}

void accept(const std::shared_ptr<Command> goal_handle)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("command"), "Starting thread to execute command");
    std::thread{std::bind(execute, std::placeholders::_1), goal_handle}.detach();
}


rclcpp_action::GoalResponse handle(const rclcpp_action::GoalUUID &uuid, std::shared_ptr<const Command::Goal> goal)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("command"), "Received command goal %d", goal->command);
    (void)uuid;
    return rclcpp_action::GoalResponse::ACCEPT_AND_EXECUTE;
}

Additionally I tried using ac_->async_get_result(future.get()), with the future from ac_->async_get_result(goal, options), but this also blocks.
